# How to pause a thread while continue others thread in C# UWP

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am building an application which will connect to Twitter, receive the tweets data and store them to database. After that, the application will retrieve the data from database, analyzed the content, if there is matching content with another pre-set database, then it will pop up a toast notification.

Total there will be 5 task need to run simultaneously.

> Task 1 => GetKeyword method (Get keyword list from database)
>
> Task 2 => Connect method (Connect to Twitter and stream data filtered by the keyword and store into database)
>
> Task 3 => RetrieveData method (Retrieve stored streamed data from database)
>
> Task 4 => Analyze method (Analyze the tweet content and found matching content)
>
> Task 5 => Notify method (If there is a match, notify the user by pop up toast notification)

So previously I managed to make them run altogether, however with these code sometimes it will stucked at `Connect` task forever and will not proceed to `RetrieveData` task and `Analyze` task.

How can I limit the runtime of `Connect` task and let it continue on `RetrieveData` task and `Analyze` task? I have already limit the number of stream data stored inside the method itself, but it seems only stopping the stream itself but not the thread.

This is the code on multi-threading:

```
List<string> streamdata = new List<string>();
List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
try
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => GetKeyword(0))
               .ContinueWith(prevTask => Connecting(1000, keyList))
               .ContinueWith(prevTask => RetrieveData(1500))
               .ContinueWith(prevTask => MakeRequest(2000, streamdata))
               .ContinueWith(prevTask => Notify(2500, cyberbully, notification));
    task.Wait();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageDialog messagebox = new MessageDialog("Task running error:" + ex);
    await messagebox.ShowAsync();
}
```

This is the Connect method Code:

```
public static void Connecting(int sleepTime, List<string> keyList)
{
    //Set the token that provided by Twitter to gain authorized access into Twitter database
    Auth.SetUserCredentials("YTNuoC9rrJs8g9kZ0hRweKrpp", "wXj6VSl68jeFStRWHDnhG19oP1WZGeBFMNgT3KCkI6MaX46SMT", "892680922322960384-8ka1NuhgiuxjSLUffQVdwmnOIbIduZa", "y92ycGrGCJS9vBJU79gq34rV6FCwNjBPFFOqhEHaTQe1l");

    //Create stream with filter stream type
    var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
    int numoftweet = 0;
    //Set language filter to English only
    stream.AddTweetLanguageFilter(LanguageFilter.English);
    //Connect to database that stored the keyword
    foreach (var key in keyList)
    {
        stream.AddTrack(key);
    }
    //Let the stream match with all the conditions stated above
    stream.MatchingTweetReceived += async (sender, argument) =>
    {
        //Connect to MongoDB server and database
        var tweet = argument.Tweet;
        try
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            var database = client.GetDatabase("StreamData");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("StreamData");
            //Exclude any Retweeted Tweets
            if (tweet.IsRetweet) return;
            //Store the data as a BsonDocument into MongoDB database
            var tweetdata = new BsonDocument
            {
                //Store only the data that needed from a Tweet
                {"Timestamp", tweet.TweetLocalCreationDate},
                {"TweetID", tweet.IdStr},
                {"TweetContent",tweet.Text},
                {"DateCreated", tweet.CreatedBy.CreatedAt.Date},
                {"UserID", tweet.CreatedBy.IdStr},
                {"Username", tweet.CreatedBy.Name}
            };
            //Insert data into MongoDB database
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(tweetdata);
            //Every tweets streamed, add 1 into the variable
            numoftweet += 1;
            //If the number of tweets exceed 100, stopped the stream
            if (numoftweet >= 100)
            {
                stream.StopStream();
            }
        }
        //Catch if any exception/errors occured
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog messagebox = new MessageDialog("MongoDB Connection Error:" + ex);
            await messagebox.ShowAsync();
        }
    };
    //Start the stream
    stream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
}
```

Remark: This is a UWP application and this code is behind a button.

Comment: The five tasks don't run "simultaneously" (nor could they, since they each depend on the previous task's result). Since your tasks are themselves likely to be asynchronous (web calls, db lookup, etc) you should look more closely at how to use `async` / `await` -- probably by starting with a simpler example problem.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yes those methods are asynchronous. I see, so instead of using Task.Run() I should use async/await for them to run?

Comment: Yes. You can just `await` each call, one after the other.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in comments, just do `await` your methods directly, without adding the `Task.Run` (looks like your methods aren't returning anything):

```
await GetKeyword(0);
await Connecting(1000, keyList);
await RetrieveData(1500);
await MakeRequest(2000, streamdata);
await Notify(2500, cyberbully, notification);
```

Sidenote: do not use the `async void` for your methods, it's only for event handlers. If your method doesn't return anything, then use `async Task`:

```
public static async Task Connecting(int sleepTime, List<string> keyList)
```

Comment: @Mr.AF Thanks, #SOReadyToHelp :)

Answer (score 1):

> How to pause a thread while continue others thread in C# UWP

you can use **ManualResetEvent**

***Notifies one or more waiting threads that an event has occurred***

[reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, so does that means I use MRE to set these 5 threads, initially with all threads waiting, start on first thread, when first thread done notify on second thread, is that how it works?

Comment: Yup check reference if it was useful don't forget to vote me up LOL !

Comment: However, I do want to know that why the second thread which is the Connect thread did not stop even I do limit the number of data streamed in the method, I stopped the stream when it reach 100 data, but the thread did not stopped so the data just stopped store into database and stop streaming but the thread itself is still running and won't enter the next thread.

Comment: @Corene i checked your code but i found no clue it need deep code research but i suggest you check if there is a loop or something that keep thread running

Comment: Hi I've updated my Connect() method code, I do try this only in another class with Console output, and it did stopped at 100 data streamed and the stream is stopped. So I have no idea why it won't stop the thread itself.

Comment: use this ManualEventRest.WaitOne()

Comment: You don't need an MRE for this -- in fact you should *never* wait on anything in the UI thread or else your app will appear hung (and may actually deadlock). Just use `await` for the asynchronous methods.